# UICollectionView not showing & delegate/datasource methods not being called

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have my data source methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 10;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    LPDiaryCollectionViewCell *cell = (LPDiaryCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.testLabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;

}
```

The cell is registered

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[LPDiaryCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Datasource, delegate and outlet are connected

[image: connections inspector connecting collectionview to delegate, datasource and outlet]

But when I run, datasource methods don't get called and view is plain white with no UICollectionView showing.

EDIT: added the uicollectionview programattically instead. It displays but still no cell.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but are the datasource methods defined in Diary View Controller?

Comment: Where did you make the cell? You shouldn't register the cell class unless you made the cell entirely in code (no xib or storyboard).

Comment: xcode do not called any of the above three method...?

Comment: @danh Yup. Cell is made programmatically - no xib, just storyboard for the collectionview but not the cell. Logs don't show them being called

Comment: Have you set up "cell" as cell identifier in IB?

Comment: Make sure you do not realloc your collectionView in code. I guess you have a collectionView in IB and you have set there delegate and datasources, then you realloc them programmatically and do not set the delegate and datasource for the new one. Try to set delegate and datasource programmatically.

Comment: @NeverHopeless yeah, I got that and logs show methods being called now. Still no cell displayed

Comment: Try to load the default cells first, so it will make sure your code is fine and problem is your cell or its registration. etc.

Comment: Got it to work! Each comment was helpful in debugging and doublechecking. Make sure it is done programmatically if you go my route. Be sure to set data source and delegate to self in code. Only one instance of the object and test with default cell.

Comment: What was the issue? facing same proble,m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set cell identifier for collection view cell in storybord(Ex. I have declared `identifier = "ReuseCell"`) and used same storyboard identifer in cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

```
static NSString *identifier = @"ReuseCell";        
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

static NSString *identifier = @"Yourcellname";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];